# slicing numpy 3-d array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 3d numpy array such as:

```
data = np.array([[[1, 2, 3, -999],
                  [5, 6, 7, 8],
                  [9, 10, 11, 12]],
             
                 [[10, 20, 30, -999],
                  [50, 60, 70, 80],
                  [90, 100, 110, 120]],
             
                 [[100, 200, 300, -999],
                  [500, 600, 700, 800],
                  [900, 1000, 1100, 1200]]])
```

Further i want to slice my array at certain random positions

```
pos = [[0, 1], [0, 2], [1, 0]]
```

to slice the array

```
slices = [data[:, p[0], p[1]] for p in pos]
```

to yield

```
[[2, 20, 200], [3, 30, 300], [5, 50, 500]]
```

What would be a faster way to perform the slicing step?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use numpy arrays instead for indexing:

```
pos = np.array([[0, 1], [0, 2], [1, 0]])
slices = data[:, pos[:, 0], pos[:, 1]].T
```

This is documented under [integer array indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#integer-array-indexing).